# If I use WriteAsync will I still have problems with when multiple backgroundworkers try to write to same .txt file?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have multiple `backgroundworkers` that all wants to write to log.txt, which results in the exception `The process cannot access the file 'C:\...\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.`. I know it's a long shot but would it help if I used `WriteAsync()` instead or would it have no effect at all?

(If that's not a simple solution, I guess I have to implement the `mutex` object I've seen before.)

```
public static void WriteToLog(string text, bool append = true)
{
    try
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt", append))
        {
            writer.Write(text);
            // writer.WriteAsync(text); // Would this 'queue up' instead of trying 
                                           to access the same process at the same time?
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR! Fejl i loggen! {ex.Message}. {ex.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should syncronize your background workers when writing into one file. Even if you solve your current problem (e.g. by opening the file as Write-shared), you can still get some garbled messages in the file if two writers happen to flush at odd times

Comment: Yes. Using mutex is still not the best solution. The best solution is to stop using stream writer for logging purposes and either switch to libraries for logging, e.g. NLog or Log4Net, which will provide best performance and concurrency; or use non-file logging storage, e.g. database.

Comment: So how do you syncronize your workers when they live in their on thread?

Comment: You really should not reinvent the wheel, there is no reason to. Use Log4Net (or NLog or something else). These libraries are well thought out and designed to be fast, robust, and flexible. There is no reason not to. Think of it this way: When you want to run an app you do not also re-write the .net framework and an operating system for it to run on right? Think of these well tested open libraries (on NuGet) the same way.

Comment: Yes it's free and small/big it does not matter. These libraries are easy to install with nuget and also easy to consumer and configure.

Comment: I agree to using those Log tools would be much better and I must admit I forget them. It was no problem, for this small project, before I added those workers.

Comment: @radbyx If you want to synchronize your workers, you can lock around some shared object, eg. `public static object WriteLock = new object()` `lock(WriteLock) {writer.Write(text);}`

Comment: Don't use BGW. First of all, use one of the many logging libraries instead of reinventing them. If you want to write asynchronously use the Task-based File methods, not BGW. No matter what you do though, file operations need synchronization. You can avoid blocking if you use a queue in front of a single background writer. You could use an ActionBlock<string> for that, or a ConcurrentQueue/Channel together with a writer task

Comment: I really can recommend logging frameworks as well. But I also see a point of implementing this on your own as you are learning how to synchronize concurrent accesses then.

Comment: Thanks for all the great inputs, I will go and think about a better solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually answer your question. No, it wont save you from the locking issue. async is not a magic keyword that will synchronize all thread. On the opposite it might even start its own thread depending on the synchronizer.

Unless you are on a single thread model then yes this will queue up since the synchronizer only has one thread to work with. It will then have to queue up all async calls with context switch. However if you are on single thread model you wouldnt have this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem with multiple ways.

1. Use a locking mechanism to synchronize access to a shared resource. One good option for this scenario is
   [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)
2. Use a logging framework(there are a lot of good libraries and very reliable).

Personally i would prefer going with a logging framework, as there are many features that you will use useful (rolling file appender, db logger, etc) that will offer you a clean solution for logging with zero hacks and maintenance.

Comment: +1 for a logging framework, third option would be to use a `Queue<string>` (or better: `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, thx Panagiotis) to collect all log messages and a single dedicated log writer that consumes the queue.

Comment: If the writer and reader are on different threads, use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead of `Queue<T>`

Answer (score 1):

While using a logging framework is the *best* solution, to specifically address the issue...

The append mode requires the file to be locked, and when a lock can't be obtained you get the error you're receiving. You could synchronize all threads but then you'd be blocking them for a time. Using `WriteAsync` does not alleviate the problem.

A better solution is to enqueue your messages and then have a dedicated thread dequeue them and write to the log. Thus, you *need no synchronization* because all writes are done by a single thread.

I will warn again: use a logging framework.